# Numpy: Get help on the add function

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write a simple NumPy program to get help on the add function using google colab notebook.

The solution is:

```
print(np.info(np.add))
```

It should return:

```
add(x1, x2[, out])

Add arguments element-wise.

Parameters
----------
x1, x2 : array_like
    The arrays to be added.  If ``x1.shape != x2.shape``, they must be
    broadcastable to a common shape (which may be the shape of one or
    the other).

Returns
-------
add : ndarray or scalar
    The sum of `x1` and `x2`, element-wise.  Returns a scalar if
    both  `x1` and `x2` are scalars.

Notes
-----
Equivalent to `x1` + `x2` in terms of array broadcasting.

Examples
--------
>>> np.add(1.0, 4.0)
5.0
>>> x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
>>> x2 = np.arange(3.0)
>>> np.add(x1, x2)
array([[  0.,   2.,   4.],
       [  3.,   5.,   7.],
       [  6.,   8.,  10.]])
None
```

But I get only:
`None`

How could I get the function documentation?

Comment: do you mean `help(np.info(np.add))`? `help(<topic>)` usually gets the short version of python documentation for a given 'topic'

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken Actually `help(np.add)` returns too extensive documentation of the `np.add` function. The right solution I found here https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/numpy/basic/numpy-basic-exercise-2.php but it did not work

Comment: `np.info` includes the `print`.  It doesn't return anything, or rather returns `None`.  There are some function that return a formatted string that you can then print, `np.info` isn't one of those.

Comment: In the notebook do a `np.info??` to see what the function actually does - the print is at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.info` doesn't return an info string. It prints straight to stdout, or another file-like object you specify.

An IPython notebook overrides `sys.stdout`, but if it does so *after* `numpy.info` grabs `sys.stdout` to use as a default parameter, then `numpy.info` ends up trying to write to the old stdout.

Tell `numpy.info` to print to the new stdout explicitly. Also, you shouldn't `print` the return value unless you actually do want to print an irrelevant `None` for some reason.

```
numpy.info(numpy.add, output=sys.stdout)
```